# How to insert several thousand columns into sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

Similar to my last question, but I ran into problem lets say I have a simple dictionary like below but its Big, when I try inserting a big dictionary using the methods below I get operational error  for the c.execute(schema) for too many columns so what should be my alternate method to populate an sql databases columns?  Using the alter table command and add each one individually?

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('simple.db')
c = con.cursor()

dic = {
    'x1':{'y1':1.0,'y2':0.0},
    'x2':{'y1':0.0,'y2':2.0,'joe bla':1.5},
    'x3':{'y2':2.0,'y3 45 etc':1.5}
    }

# 1. Find the unique column names.
columns = set()
for _, cols in dic.items():
    for key, _ in cols.items():
       columns.add(key)

# 2. Create the schema.
col_defs = [
    # Start with the column for our key name
    '"row_name" VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY'
    ]
for column in columns:
    col_defs.append('"%s" REAL NULL' % column)
schema = "CREATE TABLE simple (%s);" % ",".join(col_defs)
c.execute(schema)

# 3. Loop through each row
for row_name, cols in dic.items():

    # Compile the data we have for this row.
    col_names = cols.keys()
    col_values = [str(val) for val in cols.values()]

    # Insert it.
    sql = 'INSERT INTO simple ("row_name", "%s") VALUES ("%s", "%s");' % (
        '","'.join(col_names),
        row_name,
        '","'.join(col_values)
        )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you right, you're not trying to insert thousands of rows, but thousands of columns. [SQLite has a limit on the number of columns per table](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) (by default 2000), though this can be adjusted if you recompile SQLite. Never having done this, I do not know if you then need to tweak the Python interface, but I'd suspect not.

You probably want to rethink your design. Any non-data warehouse / OLAP application is highly unlikely to need or be terribly efficient with thousands of *columns* (rows, yes) and SQLite is *not* a good solution for a data warehouse / OLAP type situation. You may get a bit further with something like an [entity-attribute-value setup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) (not a normal recommendation for genuine relational databases, but a valid application data model and much more likely to accommodate your needs without pushing the limits of SQLite too far).

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, yes I went to sql because I hit limits with python dictionaries maxing out ram, I'm not too familiar with databases any suggestions on  an eav library interface-able with python?

Answer (score 0):

If you really are adding a massive number of rows and are running into problems, maybe your single transaction is getting too large.

Do a [COMMIT](http://sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html) (commit()) after a given number of lines (or even after each insert as a test) if that is acceptable.

Thousands of rows should be easily doable with sqlite. Getting to millions and above, at some point there might be need for more. Depends on a lot of things, of course.